# First login to Nginx-Proxy-Manager not working: pushing sign-in button does nothing

Tags: nginx, synology, portainer

I installed Nginx-Proxy-Manager and MariaDB via "App templates" through Portainer on my Synology NAS. When I visit the NPM login-page with port 81 and type in the first required login data "admin@example.com" with password "changeme" and push the sign in button nothing happens. What is the matter here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself with the help of this instruction https://www.wundertech.net/nginx-proxy-manager-synology-nas-setup-instructions/ : created a new container and configured it with the specs from wundertech.